# Why does Python's multiprocessing module only support two data types?

Tags: python, memory, concurrency, multiprocessing

According to Python's [multiprocessing documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=process):

> Data can be stored in a shared memory map using Value or Array.

Is shared memory treated differently than memory that is typically allocated to a process? Why does Python only support two data structures?

I'm guessing it has to do with garbage collection and is perhaps along the same reasons GIL exists. If this is the case, how/why are [Value](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=process#multiprocessing.Value) and [Array](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=process#multiprocessing.Array) implemented to be an exception to this?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.shared_memory.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not remotely an expert on this, so def not a complete answer.  There are a couple of things I think this considers:

- Processes have their own memory space, so if we share "normal" variables between  processes and try to write each process will have its own copy (perhaps using copy on write semantics).
- Shared memory needs some sort of abstraction or primitive as it exists outside of process memory ([SOURCE](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.shared_memory.html))
- `Value` and `Array`, by default, are thread/process safe for concurrent use by guarding access with locks, handling allocations to shared memory AND protecting it :)

The attached documentation is able to answer, **yes** to:

*is shared memory treated differently than memory that is typically allocated to a process?*

---